# Locate the value of an attribute, match and find the value on other elements and alter the css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, match

So essentially I am trying to find the value of an attribute, in this instance, 'data-location', and then search for that value elsewhere, in this instance in the form of an ID, and alter the CSS for that matched value.

I have the below so far which I thought would work, but I am not sure how to check for various different values for various elements and apply accordingly, so I have grouped the different sections in div's with classes so I can break them up from one another

Thanks guys

```js
var getvalue = $('ul#test').find('li').attr('data-location');

if( $('div.other div').attr('id').val() == getvalue ) {
 $( this ).css('background-color','red');
};
```

```css
#thebirchplot3 {
 padding:30px;
 background:#fff;
}
#theashplot3 {
 padding:30px;
 background:blue;
 color:#fff;
}
#thediveplot1 {
 padding:30px;
 background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">Change CSS based on values</h1>
<ul id="test">
    <li data-location="thebirchplot3">one</li>
    <li data-location="theashplot3">two</li>
    <li data-location="thediveplot1">three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="show">
    <li data-location="theashplot3">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="display">
    <li data-location="thediveplot1">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
------
<div>
  <div class="other">
    <div id="thebirchplot3">
    adfasdfasfsafdsafdsfsadfdsafdsafdsfafadsf
    </div>
    <div id="theashplot3">
    adfasdfasfsafdsafdsfsadfdsafdsafdsfafadsf
    </div>
    <div id="thediveplot1">
    adfasdfasfsafdsafdsfsadfdsafdsafdsfafadsf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want your JS code to work for the other `ul` ('show' and 'display') ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes please :) but they would have different colours assigned if that makes sense? This was the only way I could think it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

Working Example:-

```js
$('ul#test').find('li').each(function(){ // iterate over each li element
  var ultest = $(this); //assign current li object to variable
  $('div.other').children().each(function(){ // now iterate to each child div of other div
     if($(this).attr('id') == ultest.data('location')){ // compare id with data-location
      $( this ).css('background-color','red'); // if same then add background color
     }
  });
});
```

```css
#thebirchplot3 {padding:30px;background:#fff;}
#theashplot3 {padding:30px;background:blue;color:#fff;}
#thediveplot1 {padding:30px;background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="title">Change CSS based on values</h1>
<ul id="test">
    <li data-location="thebirchplot3">one</li>
    <li data-location="theashplot3">two</li>
    <li data-location="thediveplot1">three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="show">
    <li data-location="theashplot3">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="display">
    <li data-location="thediveplot1">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
------
<div>
  <div class="other">
    <div id="thebirchplot3">
    this is dummy
    </div>
    <div id="thebirchplot355435">
    text
    </div>
    <div id="theashplot3">
    which shows you
    </div>
    <div id="theashplot35465464">
    that everything
    </div>
    <div id="thediveplot1">
    working fine now
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie This is really helpful, thanks.  I have added it into a fiddle and it works as I wanted it to.  I feel there is probably a cleaner way of finding the elements but this does answer my question, so thanks :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie done, thank you :) Could you kindly amend your answer to remove the unnecessary html I included for others? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure ok :) Just the two input fields I have now omitted from my question. Sorry I can't upvote as I'm quite new here :(

Comment: @user4329628  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Done :)

Answer (score 2):

use jquery `find()` method for your requirement as

```
var getvalue = $('ul#test').find('li').attr('data-location');

$('div.other').find('#'+getvalue).css('background-color','red');
```

working fiddle is [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b36xb8xv/1/)

Comment: This works well to colour all the divs with that value, but I require the variable to find each li element and check each, rather than just one?  Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: this works but for single-one (not each li value).Still +1 for good effort.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yeah, as the script wrote in question, i wrote accordingly